# Как написать триггер на сохранение первоначального значения одной колонки в другой?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как написать триггер на сохранение первоначального значения одной колонки в другой?

При появлении новой записи значение из поля PlannedWork должно переноситься в поле PlannedWorkBaseLine и более не меняться, поскольку в поле PlannedWork далее просто меняется числовое значение в большую или меньшую сторону.

SQL сервер 11.0.3000.0

Созданный мною код постоянно меняет PlannedWorkBaseLine из значения PlannedWork:

```
USE [ProjectWebApp1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NEW_MSP_TimesheetActual]
ON  [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @PlannedWorkBaseLineNew DECIMAL
DECLARE @TimesheetLineUIDNew UID
DECLARE @TimeByDayNew DATETIME
DECLARE @PlannedWorkNew DECIMAL
DECLARE @PlannedWorkBaseLineOld DECIMAL
DECLARE @TimesheetLineUIDOld UID
DECLARE @TimeByDayOld DATETIME
DECLARE @PlannedWorkOld DECIMAL
SELECT @PlannedWorkBaseLineNew=INSERTED.PlannedWorkBaseLine, @TimesheetLineUIDNew=INSERTED.TimesheetLineUID, @TimeByDayNew=INSERTED.TimeByDay, @PlannedWorkNew=INSERTED.PlannedWork,
@PlannedWorkBaseLineOld=DELETED.PlannedWorkBaseLine,@TimesheetLineUIDOld=DELETED.TimesheetLineUID, @TimeByDayOld=DELETED.TimeByDay, @PlannedWorkOld=DELETED.PlannedWork
FROM INSERTED
FULL OUTER JOIN DELETED ON ((INSERTED.TimesheetLineUID = DELETED.TimesheetLineUID) and (INSERTED.TimeByDay = DELETED.TimeByDay))
UPDATE [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual]
SET [PlannedWorkBaseLine] = @PlannedWorkNew WHERE [TimesheetLineUID]=@TimesheetLineUIDNew and [TimeByDay]=(@TimeByDayNew) and (@PlannedWorkOld IS NULL)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

В `[dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual]` поле `[PlannedWorkBaseLine]` делаем nullable. И если в нем `NULL` - пишем новое значение. Если там уже есть значение - не трогаем. Код триггера будет таким:

```
USE [ProjectWebApp1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NEW_MSP_TimesheetActual]
ON  [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE ta
SET [PlannedWorkBaseLine] = PlannedWork  
FROM [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual] ta
INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON ta.ID = i.ID  -- здесь нужно соединение по ключу
WHERE ta.[PlannedWorkBaseLine] IS NULL

END
```

Также, надо учитывать, что может быть добавлено несколько строк.

Comment: У Вас видимо ошибка. Видио хотели указать WHERE ta.[PlannedWorkBaseLine] IS NULL

Comment: @Василий Благодарю! Исправил.

Comment: Теперь триггер работает как в моем предыдущем коде - всегда сохраняет предыдущее значение, а мне необходимо получить только самое первое значение: ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[NEW_MSP_TimesheetActual]
ON  [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE tsa
SET [PlannedWorkBaseLine] = tsa.PlannedWork
FROM [dbo].[MSP_TimesheetActual] tsa
INNER JOIN inserted i
    ON tsa.TimesheetLineUID = i.TimesheetLineUID and tsa.TimeByDay = i.TimeByDay
WHERE tsa.[PlannedWorkBaseLine] IS NULL
END

Comment: Это странно, надо проверить. А вообще зачем триггер? Если можно в поле при добавлении записи сразу записать неделе значение и не трогать его потом.